# How to add parameters to mvcSiteMapNode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I have an action in controller:

```
    public ActionResult Close(DocType docType)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

where DocType is a simple enum.
I want to have 2 different links to the same action but with different parameters. I have tried this:

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Accounting" clickable="false" imageUrl="~/Content/Images/Buttons/MenuButtons/billing.png" visibility="path">
       <mvcSiteMapNode title="Payments" controller="Payment" action="Index"></mvcSiteMapNode>
       <mvcSiteMapNode title="Closing WO" controller="Payment" action="Close" docType="2"></mvcSiteMapNode>
       <mvcSiteMapNode title="Closing WS" controller="Payment" action="Close" docType="4"></mvcSiteMapNode>
   </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

But in the menu I have 2 links without any parameters: "/Payments/Close"

What's wrong?
How to add parameters into mvcSiteMapNode?

Here are my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a routing problem. Please show your routing configuration. Do you have a route with a `{docType}` parameter as well?

Comment: No, I don't have such route. I would like to use only default route with optional id parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your default route, you have to use `id` for the route key (since it only supports the keys `controller`, `action` and `id`). If you don't, you will get a route with a query string `?docType=2`, since this is extra undefined information that is not part of the route.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Accounting" clickable="false" imageUrl="~/Content/Images/Buttons/MenuButtons/billing.png" visibility="path">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Payments" controller="Payment" action="Index"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Closing WO" controller="Payment" action="Close" id="2"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Closing WS" controller="Payment" action="Close" id="4"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

---

```
public ActionResult Close(DocType id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Otherwise, you need to have a route with the key `{docType}`. Either way, the key names must match in order to generate URLs correctly (as they need to in MVC when using `ActionLink`).